# Turn off scientific notation in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I would like to prevent Excel behavior that any large number I enter is stored as a number, then abbreviated to scientific notation.
Is it possible to tell Excel 2007 to stop doing this?

Comment: Possibly relevant if you're importing a file: [How can you make Excel 2007 stop formatting large numbers as scientific notation?](http://superuser.com/questions/37975/how-can-you-make-excel-2007-stop-formatting-large-numbers-as-scientific-notation)

Comment: Another possibly relevant question: [Why does Excel treat long numeric strings as scientific notation even after changing cell format to text](http://superuser.com/questions/413226/why-does-excel-treat-long-numeric-strings-as-scientific-notation-even-after-chan)

Comment: And if you actually need to work with large numbers, there's an add-in, as mentioned an answer to in this question: [Why is Excel truncating my 16-digit numbers?](http://superuser.com/questions/437764/why-is-excel-truncating-my-16-digit-numbers)

Comment: The best option to workaroung that sh**t is to use **Google Sheets**.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Unfortunately excel does not allow you to turn this functionality off by default.

However if you select your data, right click, and click "Format cells..." and choose Number you can stop excel from changing your data to scientific notation.

Comment: I would argue that your modification to the question changes its meaning. Excel only accepts numerical data up to a certain precision, so there's a distinction between storing as text (essentially unlimited precision, but difficult to manipulate) and storing as a number. The original question did ask how to store as text by default. And then there's how the (imprecise?) number is displayed, which the modified question and your answer address.

Comment: You are right when you say that if the asker wants to actually store as text my answer would be incorrect. He can clarify later if my answer is not satisfactory and we can look at other solutions.

Comment: Please note that while saving your file it goes back to same scientific notation.

Comment: Keep in mind however that if there are more than 15 digits in the number excel will convert the digits at the end to "0"

Seriously... it will do that...

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/269370

Comment: This worked perfectly in Excel 2016 for Mac - set display format to `numbers`, then `Save As...` and choose `Text File (tab delimited) *.txt` or whatever, and it saved without exponential formatting.

Comment: The issue is that excel loses the data when you open a csv file. It cannot be stopped from truncating really long numbers such as 20 digit SIM card ICCIDs.

Comment: Select the Cell, format it as Text, press F2 key and then Return key.

Comment: I really do not enjoy working with Excel...

Comment: After 35 years of Excel, and you still can't export to CSV correctly by default. Issues to keep in mind (Excel 365): (1) Numbers larger than some N digits will either be truncated or (b) removing ending `0`s. (c) Selecting cell and format as *text* **is not doing the same** as if you select multiple cells and formatting as text, which has no effect on large numbers, and insists displaying in scientific notation. Absurd!

Answer (score 30):

This is inconvenient (yet effective) hack.  Note, this is only really useful if you need to import the full number into another application (like Access) or provide the proper display.

If you format the column in question as `number`, you can copy all correctly formatted numbers into Notepad.  Then just create a new column formatted as `text`, and copy the Notepad representation into the new column.

Comment: The only truly correct answer

Comment: This worked for me. I am trying to import with SSIS. Thank you! +1

Comment: This is the answer worked for me.

Comment: This works. Poor excel and ms...

Comment: It looks long winded, but only takes a few seconds and works exactly as described. Worked for me after I've tackled this problem so many times, and nothing else worked. I'm dealing with tables of ICCID numbers on SIM cards, eg '89610180000676404041'. In the modern tech world large integers are commonplace. Excel seems to be stuck in the 1990s.

Answer (score 21):

Maybe scientific notation is one of the less useful Excel behaviour.

If you have a scientific notation in the A1 cell you cant just use this formula to have a text formatted value in the B1 cell:

`=CONCATENATE(A1)`

This is an example of the results:

```
+----+--------------------------+-------------------------+
|    |            A             |            B            |
+----+--------------------------+-------------------------+
|  1 | Ugly scientific notation | Awesome numbers as text |
|  2 | 8,80001E+11              | 880001465055            |
|  3 | 8,80001E+11              | 880001445410            |
|  4 | 8,80001E+11              | 880001455678            |
|  5 | 8,80001E+11              | 880001441264            |
|  6 | 8,80001E+11              | 880001413012            |
|  7 | 8,80001E+11              | 880001391343            |
|  8 | 8,80001E+11              | 880001373652            |
|  9 | 8,80001E+11              | 880001273395            |
| 10 | 8,80001E+11              | 880001115228            |
| 11 | 8,80001E+11              | 880001185106            |
| 12 | 8,80001E+11              | 880001062936            |
| 13 | 8,80001E+11              | 880000796522            |
| 14 | 8,80001E+11              | 880000890200            |
| 15 | 8,80001E+11              | 880000596278            |
| 16 | 8,8E+11                  | 880000243378            |
| 17 | 8,8E+11                  | 880000069050            |
| 18 | 8,85101E+11              | 885100625390            |
+----+--------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: `=TEXT(A1, "0")` also works, as does probably a billion other formulas

Comment: This is a lot like the notepad answer above, but doesn't require an external application.  I like it for that reason.

Comment: It's we're comparing formulaic methods, I would argue `=A1&""` is the shortest, therefore best.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make ALL numbers typed within a sheet NOT to appear in scientific format, you can consider [creating a template & reusing it](http://mypchell.com/guides/73-how-to-create-and-use-excel-templates).

When you create the template, select the whole sheet and set the default number format for all cells to "Number".

Comment: Can you override the default excel template with this so that it is kind of "permanent" ?

Answer (score 2):

One workaround I use when pasting in tab-delimited data that contains long numeric codes is to set the cell format **before** I paste the data.

### If you're pasting into a blank sheet

1. Select all (Ctrl+A).
2. Format the cells as "text" (Ctrl+1 to bring up the format menu).
3. Paste your data (Ctrl+V).

### If you're pasting in a section

1. Paste the tab-delimited data into Excel, and leave it as selected.
2. Press the delete key. This will delete the new data, but will *keep the cells selected*.
3. Set the format of the selected cells to be "text" (Ctrl+1 to bring up format menu)
4. Paste the new data in again

It seems that Excel will leave the numeric codes alone if the cells are already set as text, but will otherwise treat them irreversibly as numbers.

Comment: This doesn't work in many cases.  Excel in office 365 seems to be changing the format.  You can select the whole column, change to Text, copy in a long number, and the format is switched automatically to General.

Comment: @Rob Yes, Office 365/Microsoft 365 is a different product in many ways, from Microsoft Office, reference in the question. I don't use it myself, but I'm sure it has functional differences.

Comment: does not work, even if you put format cell as text, is does convert to scientific notation

Comment: @serge, which version of Excel are you using? This question is about the desktop application, not the Office 365 web application.

Comment: @Giles, the MS Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO version 2301, is a desktop application

Answer (score 0):

The only real answer is to store it as text.

1. Paste the column in A.
2. In B,  =""&A1&""(two double quotes)

(adds quotes to it, forcing text)

If it's a CSV, store the number as quotes beforehand.

"1234", "1234"

Comment: That doesn't work for CSV files. Even if it is in quotes, it will still treat it as a number.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is being rolled out gradually: https://insider.microsoft365.com/en-us/blog/control-data-conversions-in-excel

I had the following prompt once, but the functionality and option have disappeared since:

> By default, Excel will perform the following data conversions in this file:
>
> • Convert large numbers into scientific notation
>
> Do you want to permanently keep these conversions?
>
> [ ] Don't notify me about default conversions in .csv or similar files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have finally been resolved. Posting this here in case others find this 12 year old question as I did.

If you go to Options -> Data you will find a section enabling you to control what automatic conversions are performed.

[image]