# Editing CSV file in Excel always converts number column to scientific notation

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, csv

I have a CSV file that I'm editing in Excel 2013. In the file there is a column that contains numbers e.g **688087123456789**. Everytime I open the CSV file in Excel, it converts the number to scientific notation **6.88087E+14**. I can revert the number back to its original format by right-clicking the cell > Format Cells > Custom and then selecting 0.

However, I do not want to do this process everytime I open teh CSV file. How can I do this?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/452832/turn-off-scientific-notation-in-excel

Comment: That does not help. This continues to occur with CSV files that are *opened*, rather than pasted. The solution is to open the file in notepad and paste into Excel or use the data import wizard.

Answer (score 1):

It is still not possible, as already answered [here](https://superuser.com/a/452845/285900). You may only use an alternative approach described [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/disabling-scientific-notation/943b8103-8c50-451d-8037-c697422e2307):

> Stop double-clicking the .TXT/.CSV file or opening the text file
>   conventionally (e.g. CTRL+O) and use the Text Import Wizard to specify
>   Text format for certain fields within your import file. Start by
>   opening Excel to a blank workbook and from the Data tab's Get External
>   Data group, click the From Text button.
>
> After clicking From Text, select your text file from the Import Text
>   File dialog and click Open. This launches the Text Import Wizard.
>   There are three pages to complete. The first page is essentially to
>   determine whether the file is to be considered Delimited or Fixed
>   Width. The second page depends upon the first. You will be asked what
>   characters to consider as delimiters or asked to choose the widths of
>   a fixed width file.
>
> The third page is what is going to help you determine the format of
>   each field. Select your account id field from the Data preview at the
>   bottom then select Text from the Column data format list in the upper
>   left. Note that the header of the field in the bottom Data preview has
>   changed to Text. Repeat for any other fields and click Finish in the
>   lower right to complete your operation.

Another way is to use VBA script, like [the one here](https://superuser.com/a/307498/285900).